# Examples on how to log the sync procedure

Tags: c#, microsoft-sync-framework

I have implemented a sync and it works fine. Since the sync is rather lengthy (in time) I want to create a `ProgressBar` that shows the progress of the sync. I have looked at some sync events, like `ApplyingChanges`.

However I'm not getting them as I expect, and the documentation isn't giving me much help either.

Does anyone have a link to some good examples on how the sync logging works? I would be very thankful.

(I'm using Sync framework 2.1)

For example, Isn't there any events between the `ApplyingChanges` and the `ChangesApplied` events?

Comment: Which version of Microsoft Sync Framework?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately I need to apologize that I cannot show code due to I am not working anymore for the project where we were using Microsoft Sync Framework 2.1. Hopefully the explanation will give you a step forward in the right direction.

In Microsoft Sync Framework 2.1 you have the ability to subscribe to the session progress event: `Microsoft.Synchronization.SyncOrchestrator.SessionProgress`. To be honest. i didn't get a reliable progress bar using this event. So I gathered the information by myself from the two sync providers.

I have only experience with the `DatabaseSyncProvider` (Which inherits `RelationalSyncProvider`) but hopefully helps you out.
A `RelationalSyncProvider` is raising some events which can help you out gathering information:
[See RelationalSyncProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.synchronization.data.relationalsyncprovider_events(v=sql.105).aspx)

Be aware that twoway synchronization means two sync sessions. Its recommended to calculate the progress for each sessions. So in case of bi-directional synchronization, once one session is completed, you are on 50 percent.

For more advanced progress bars, you need to know how many records you are going to synchronize. In combination with the gathered information from the events of the RelationalSyncProvider, you can build a quite accurate progressbar. For that you can just build a kind of preview, which is counting the changes which will be synchronized during the next session.
For that you can use the `SyncKnowledge` from the Target side and the `selectchanges` queries on the Source side database. The whereclause of the `selectchanges` queries, can be used for your own `countchanges` stored procedures. Due to you are using the same whereclause as MS Sync Framework is using to select changes, you will retrieve the exact amount of records which will be send synchronized for that session.

We are using this 'countchanges' not only for progress bars but also for statistics and advanced scheduling. If you are only going it for a progressbar you need to make a decision between performance penalty and a user friendly progressbar or having a less reliable progress bar.

Comment: Hadn't heard of the `SessionProgress` before, tried it, and it occurred two times during the sync. First time at 50 / 100 and second time 100 / 100...
However I did know about the provider events, but as I said in my last edit, most of the sync time is spent between the client's ApplyingChanges and ChangesApplied, and there I seem to get no other events...

Comment: Thats true. The SessionProgress is not accurate. The SessionProgress depends on how many sessions you have. 1 session: (One way sync) will be 0-100%. If you are syncing bi-directional. The 50% means that the first session is finished and it starts with the second session. So Not accurate at all

Comment: I cannot recall what is in between ApplyingChanges and ChangesApplied. The most information I used in my progress bar was comming from the SyncProgress of the sync providers. Also we used statistics to forecast the duration between two phases of the sync process. Start session -> Determine Changes -> Send Changes -> Apply Changes -> Finished session